# Python Django Form: Setting initial values for CharFields

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm writing a webpage as part of a larger django project that allows an existing user to change his personal information.  The issue is that the form needs to access the user's existing information. I want to set it so that the existing info appears in each CharField when the page loads, and the user can make their appropriate changes, and accept. The page loads, but the charfields don't appear at all. This is what I have so far:

class EditPersonForm(forms.Form):

```
"""
Form that allows for editing an existing user's (of Person class) personal information.
Same structure as the RegistrationForm. 
The CharField's look the same as the registration page, but have the existing info already filled out.
"""

#the following line are all indented under the class definition, dont know why it's showing up weird here

def __init__(self, person):
    profile = person

    profile_default = {"username" : profile.user.username, "email" : profile.user.email, "first_name" : profile.user.first_name, \
        "last_name" : profile.user.last_name, "street_address" : profile.street_address, "apt_number" : profile.apt_number, \
        "city" : profile.city, "state" : profile.city, "zipcode" : profile.zipcode}

    username       = forms.CharField(label =('User Name'), max_length = constants.MAX_LEN_NAME, initial = profile_default.username)
    email          = forms.EmailField(label = ('Email Address'), initial = profile_default.email)
    first_name     = forms.CharField(label = ('First Name'), max_length = constants.MAX_LEN_NAME, initial = profile_default.first_name)
    last_name      = forms.CharField(label = ('Last Name'), max_length = constants.MAX_LEN_NAME, initial = profile_default.last_name)
    street_address = forms.CharField(label = ('Street Address'), max_length = constants.MAX_LEN_NAME, initial = profile_default.street_address)
    apt_number     = forms.CharField(label = ('Apartment Number'), required = False, max_length = constants.MAX_LEN_SHORTF, initial = profile_default.apt_number)
    city           = forms.CharField(label = ('City'), max_length = constants.MAX_LEN_NAME, initial = profile_default.city)
    state          = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(),choices = constants.STATE_CHOICES, initial = profile_default.state)
    zipcode        = forms.CharField(label = ('Zipcode'), max_length = constants.MAX_LEN_SHORTF, initial = profile_default.zipcode)
    password       = forms.CharField(label = ('Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False), max_length = constants.MAX_LEN_NAME)

    class Meta:
        """
        Class that allows the form to use the Person
        object model as a guideline.
        """
        model = Person
        exclude = ('user',)
```

Answer (score 1):

For each field in the `__init__` method you need to this:

```
class EditPersonForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, person, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditPersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        profile = person

        [...] #ommited code for simplification

        self.fields['username']= forms.CharField(
           label =('User Name'), max_length = constants.MAX_LEN_NAME, 
           initial = profile_default.username)

        [...] # do the same for rest of the fields
```

Also since you are defining a `model` in class `Meta`, are you suppose to be using a `ModelForm`

```
class EditPersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditPersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        [...]


    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('user',)
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Have you considered using django `UpdateView` http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.7/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/

Comment: A old but very good article on django dynamic form fields: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/

Comment: I made your suggested changes, and now some of the charfields are showing up, but only from street_address downward. and the initial values aren't showing up, which leads my to believe initial may not be the correct argument for achieving that. should i ditch my current solution and try to use UpdateView instead?

Comment: the fields that show up are the ones ive defined myself. (username, password, firstname lastname don't appear)

Comment: Please could you update your question with your new code. 'UpdateView' is meant to be for this sort of scenarios.. whether you use it or not.. it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point doing this. Fields should be defined at the class level, not inside the `__init__` method: the only reason to do that would be on those occasions when you want to override some aspects of some fields programmatically. Move all those definitions outside the method, and remove their `initial` attributes.

Instead, pass the `initial` dict as a keyword parameter when you instantiate the form in your view:

```
form = EditPersonForm(initial=profile_default)
```